# Equal for class objects in c#

Tags: c#

```
 class A
    {
     public int i;
        public A()
        {
            i = 10;
        }
     }

  class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


    A a = new A();  // creating class object
    A b = new A();// creating class object

    if (a.Equals(b)) // checking whether they are equal not by ==
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Both objects are equal ");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Both objects are not equal ");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}

// O/P : Both objects are not equal
        }
    }
```

I have declared two object of class `A`. Both are initialized with data member value `i = 10` in the constructor. But on comparing the objects, the output is "Both objects are not equal".

I would like to know why the objects are not equal.

Comment: Their respective references are not the same. From documentation: `If the current instance is a reference type, the Equals(Object) method tests for reference equality, and a call to the Equals(Object) method is equivalent to a call to the ReferenceEquals method. Reference equality means that the object variables that are compared refer to the same object.`

Comment: if you want to compare the values you would have to do a.i == b.i. However, I think you are comparing memory references Using Class.Equals.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an object is equal to a new object of the same class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20701507/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-is-equal-to-a-new-object-of-the-same-class)

Answer (score 2):

> As per my knowledge "Equal" for reference type object compare reference content.

No. The default `Equals` implementation only compares the **references**, not the *content* in those references. And `a` and `b` in your example are two different instances of `A`, so two different references.

To make your `Equals` work you need to override `Equals` (and `GetHashCode` so that it returns equal hashes for instances where `Equals` will return `true` and ideally different hashes for non-equal instances):

```
class A
{
     public int i;
     public A()
     {
         i = 10;
     }
     public override bool Equals(object o)
     {
         return (o as A)?.i == this.i;
     }
     public override int GetHashCode()
     {
         return i.GetHashCode();
     }
 }
```

Comment: @mahibatra yes, `StringBuilder` has [it's own `Equals` overload](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs,d667f7b9914a12ec)

Comment: But if i use stringbuilder object e.g  StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder('H', 'I');
            StringBuilder s2 = new StringBuilder('H', 'I'); Then s1.Equal(s2) return true. Here references are different for s1 and s2 Then why s1.Equal(s2) return true.

Comment: @mahibatra see above comment.

Answer (score 0):

The `Equals()` method tests if two refrences refer to the same instance of a class, specifically if the two references contain the same adress in memory. In your case `a.Equals(b)` returns `false` because you created two different instances of the class `A` so they don't contain the same adress in memory. For example `a.Equals(b)` would return `true` in the following case:

```
  A a = new A();
  A b = a;
```

Because `a` and `b` are now pointing to the same object in the memory (they share the same adress in memory).