# xUnit Equal two same collections, same order, same types, returns false

Tags: c#, xunit

Shouldn't xUnit Equal method return true if two collections are equal meaning have same objects in the same order?

Example:

```
var result = new List<item>()
            {
                new item()
                {
                    TypeId = typesEnum.Integer,
                    Code = "code"
                },
                new item()
                {
                   TypeId = typesEnum.Integer,
                   Code = "code2"
                }
            }
```

and Assert.Equal(expectedResult, result) returns false.

and I have exactly the same list in expectedResult, checked one by one, every property, type, everything. When I write my own IEqualityComparer and compare every single property of item class in it then the result is true. But default comparer returns false. Is that how it's supposed to work for xUnit? If so the question is how to compare if two collections are equal like equivalent?

Custom comparer looks like this:

```
internal class ItemComparer : IEqualityComparer<Item>
{
    public bool Equals(Item x, Item y)
    {
        return x.Code.Equals(y.Code) && x.TypeId.Equals(y.TypeId)
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Item obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Here's a link to similiar question:
[CLICK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419659/xunit-assert-two-listt-are-equal)

And the answer is that it should work like I think it should without having to write my own comparer. The question is why doesn't it?

I use xUnit 2.4.1

Comment: "But default comparer returns false." Well yes, if you haven't overridden Equals and GetHashCode in `item`, then two distinct objects are non-equal, even if they have the same properties. You don't need to write your own comparer, but you do need to make sure that equal objects report equality as you want them to.

Comment: That custom comparer is buggy, btw. Since equality is going by `Code` and `TypeId` but `GetHashCode` is not it is possible for it to return `true` for `cmp.Equals(x, y)` but false for `cmp.GetHashCode(x) == cmp.GetHashCode(y)`.

Comment: What do you mean I don't have to use custom comparer but make sure that equal objects report equality as I want them to? Isn't that making custom comparer, per se? When it comes to comparer, it's just a quick example.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an XUnit issue or particularity, but how C# works. When you have two objects non-primitive, with the same values inside, they are equivalent but not equals - internally they have different memory references for each property. You can even try to compare both using `==` or `.Equals()` inside an if statement, and it will return false.

[This answer explains very well about this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20701995/5120498)

What you could do:

- Overwrite comparison operators and use `Assert.True()`, and compare them in order to return a true;
- Use a library that provides a comparison by equivalency, like [FluentAssertion](https://fluentassertions.com/documentation/): `object1.Should().BeEquivalentTo(object2);`